# Write Double Quotation Mark

Tags: vb6

I am trying to overwrite specific lines in a sequential file
For example if file has:

```
"1"
"Kii"
"Kii"
"Kii"
"Kii"
"2"
"Troy Martinez"
"Edoy"
"Edoy"
"69"
"3"
"Snoop Dogg"
"Weed"
"President Troy"
"420"
```

And I have this code to overwrite

```
Private Sub OverWrite()
    Dim Count As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrSub

    LineCount = 1
    Open App.Path & "\Data.txt" For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        If LineCount < ((IDCount - 1) * 5) + 1 Or LineCount >= (IDCount * 5) + 1 Then
            For Count = 0 To 4
                Input #1, TextTemp
                FileText = FileText & """ & Text1(Count) & """ & vbCrLf
                LineCount = LineCount + 1
            Next Count
        Else
            For Count = 0 To 4
                Input #1, TextTemp
                FileText = FileText & """ & TextTemp & """ & vbCrLf
                LineCount = LineCount + 1
            Next Count
        End If
    Loop
    Close
    Open App.Path & "\Data.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, FileText
    Close
ErrSub:
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Assuming my IDCount is 2, the text file becomes

```
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & TextTemp & "
" & TextTemp & "
" & TextTemp & "
" & TextTemp & "
" & TextTemp & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
" & Text1(Count) & "
```

How do I fix this? Thanks
I am very noob

Edit: My Option Explicit Is

```
Option Explicit
    Dim IDCount As Integer
    Dim LineCount As Integer
    Dim FileText As String
    Dim TextTemp
```

Answer (score 2):

4 quotes (`""""`) escape a single quote (`"`) so:

```
FileText = FileText & """" & Text1(Count) & """" & vbCrLf
```

(`chr$(34)` also outputs a `"`)

Comment: Slight error here, although the example is correct: two quotes escape a single quote, not four.  For example, `myPath = "c:\""Microsoft SQL Server""\"` is correct if the path is `c:\"Microsoft SQL Server"\`. It's easy to confuse because four quotes is the way to show a single quote concatenated. Of course, you know this, but I'm pointing it out for the OP's benefit.